# Framework not found Pods_Bloom

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a project, using frameworks installed from cocoaPods. My project called Bloom

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/zkid18/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bloom-fcfdplwgevwopzhcpgpwppcrpbqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gifu'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/zkid18/Desktop/wrk/Bloom/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F22.30.51'


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/zkid18/Desktop/wrk/Bloom/build/Debug-iphoneos'


ld: framework not found Pods_Bloom


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve it

Comment: Are you running the xcworkspace project? Do you have other pods that are found?

Comment: @smokigouster yes, xcworkspace and, actually I have 4 pods, but I can't get what is Pods_Bloom. Bloom is my project name. From pods I have only firebase pods

Comment: i am having the same problem, did you find a solution?